Can anyone use @tasks.loop with "time" parameter? (discord.py)
@tasks.loop() didn't work.
I want to write some task that fires daily about specific hour. I copied and pasted example code from the discord.py documentation, but it didn't work. No errors, no warnings just nothing. I set up all intents and administrator permission on my bot. Of course I've changed time parameters to few minutes after my current time.
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from config import TEST_SERVER
import pytz

utc = pytz.UTC

time = datetime.time(hour=10, minute=35, tzinfo=utc) 


class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.my_task.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.my_task.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(time = time)
    async def my_task(self):
        print("My task is running!")

    @commands.command()
    async def test_ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Test ping")

async def setup(bot:commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot), guild=TEST_SERVER)


I've only added the test ping command, which works, setup and pytz for timezone aware.
Someone know why what's going on?

Unfortunatly you can't pass a variable in a @decorator like this in python. You will need to modify the task attribute, or directly in the task.loop write the expression. Could you link in the comments or include in your question the example code you took from the documentation ?

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Thanks for providing the link, I was wrong about the variable in the decorator. I tried your code and except the missing async for the cog_unload method (replace with: async def cog_unload(self):), everything work well. Does your test_ping command send the "Test ping" message ?

You are using tzinfo=utc this ensures the timer will run for Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). UTC+0 is what utc means in this case. You are probably setting up the timer for your time zone when you should be setting up for utc. Current UTC time
I also run the code and it works perfectly after setting for UTC time.
